# Android random number generator used in two classes

Tags: java, android

How do I use the same randomNumber in both of the public classes below, as you can see they both have a random number generator. I need to use the same random number for both.

At the moment they both work, but the text doesn't match the image as they're getting different random numbers

Any ideas?

```
public String getItem() {
    // Set vars
    String item = "";

    Random randomGen = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGen.nextInt(mitems.length);

    item = mitems[randomNumber];

    return item;

}

public int getImg() {
    // Set vars
    int pic;

    Random randomGen = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGen.nextInt(mitems.length);

    pic = mPics[randomNumber];

    return pic;

}
```

This is how they being accessed...

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String item = mItemBook.getItem();
            int pic = mItemBook.getImg();

            // Update text view with item
            mInfoText.setText(item);
            mImage.setImageResource(pic);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Don't generate the random number twice. Just generate it once and pass it to `getImg` and `getItem`, adding a helper method to know how many items there are:

```
public int numItems() { return mitems.length; }

public String getItem(int id) {

    return mitems[id];

}

public int getImg(int id) {

    return pic = mPics[id];

}
```

Your onClick can now just get the number of items, and pick one randomly:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int id = r.nextInt(mItemBook.numItems());
        String item = mItemBook.getItem(id);
        int pic = mItemBook.getImg(id);

        // Update text view with item
        mInfoText.setText(item);
        mImage.setImageResource(pic);
```

For that matter, don't keep constructing `Random` instances. Construct one, and keep it in a field. It's better practice since constructing objects needlessly when they can be re-used can lead to performance or memory issues in many cases. While in an onClick method that may not be the case, it's better to have good habits now rather than later.

Comment: Could you tell me how i would go about that please

Comment: @CarlR Updated answer in its entirety.